# Local video won't play in iOS 6 iPad app

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios6

I haven't played a video file in iOS before, so I'm not sure if I'm just missing something. Th e player opens but it gets stuck with the loading animation and I can't hit the Done button. Could it be that my video file isn;t supported? I encoded it for ipad.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIButton *video_btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    video_btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
    [video_btn setTitle:@"Moonrise" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [video_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(playMovie:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:video_btn];



}

-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{

    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"moonrise" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I get this as the output:

```
2012-09-25 12:47:56.206 App[4895:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-09-25 12:47:56.207 App[4895:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-09-25 12:47:56.221 App[4895:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-09-25 12:47:56.222 App[4895:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-09-25 12:47:56.226 App[4895:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-09-25 12:47:56.255 App[4895:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your MPMoviePlayerController as a property.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
```

---

To automatically close you have to set a notification in your MPMoviePlayerController. Like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];
```

This will call the function - videoFinishedCallback when video ends.
Then, you implement the callback:

```
- (void) videoFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    //remove notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:object:moviePlayerController];

    // here you set your code to remove the video
    // for example, you can remove from superview and set value to nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I have the video automatically close?